# HAproxy.cfg syntax: how to recognise SSTP other than by SNI

Tags: linux-networking, https, haproxy, sstp

I've recently managed to configure HAproxy.cfg to run HTTPS and SSTP on the same port, and can recognise some website traffic by SNI. However, as I have multiple domains I would prefer to recognise SSTP and have HTTPS as the default_backend.
[How to configure HAproxy with SSTP and HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/919076/how-to-configure-haproxy-with-sstp-and-https/919689#919689)

If I compare SSTP and HTTPS with tshark, I see the following differences:

HTTPS using IP address:

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        ....      
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 61
            Extension: status_request (len=5)
                Type: status_request (5)
                Length: 5
                Certificate Status Type: OCSP (1)
                Responder ID list Length: 0
                Request Extensions Length: 0
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension
                    Renegotiation info extension length: 0
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
                Type: SessionTicket TLS (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 8
                Supported Groups List Length: 6
                Supported Groups (3 groups)
                    Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=22)
            ...
```

HTTPS using domainname:

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        ....      
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 331
            Extension: status_request (len=5)
                Type: status_request (5)
                Length: 5
                Certificate Status Type: OCSP (1)
                Responder ID list Length: 0
                Request Extensions Length: 0
            Extension: server_name (len=26)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 26
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 24
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 21
                    Server Name: www.example.com
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension
                    Renegotiation info extension length: 0
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
                Type: SessionTicket TLS (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 8
                Supported Groups List Length: 6
                Supported Groups (3 groups)
                    Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=22)
            ...
```

SSTP:

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        ....      
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 45
            Extension: SessionTicket TLS (len=0)
                Type: SessionTicket TLS (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=22)
            ...
            Extension: heartbeat (len=1)
                Type: heartbeat (15)
                Length: 1
                Mode: Peer allowed to send requests (1)
```

Is there a way in the haproxy.cfg syntax to check for **Certificate Status Type: OCSP** or **Extension: heartbeat** ?

Answer (score 0):

Cracked this one too.

By looking merely for the presence of an SNI then I don't need to list every domain, and I can put up with IPv4 addresses failing.

```
frontend  main 192.168.0.3:443 ssl
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type }
    use_backend websites if { req_ssl_sni -m found }
    default_backend          sstp
```

I eventually found the syntax documentation at
https://www.haproxy.com/de/documentation/hapee/1-7r1/traffic-management/acls/